# Finding the position of a symbol in unsigned char and extracting contents between indexes?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an Arduino function that must take a `byte` type as an argument. In Arduino, `byte*` is also an `unsigned char*`

```
// payload is A0:433.33

void someFunction(byte* payload) {

    char* pos;
    pos = strstr(payload, ":");
    // want to eventually end up with a variable containing 'A0'
    // and another containing '433.33'

}
```

The `payload` will be something like `A0:433.22`

I want to extract `A0` and `433.22`, put them into variables, etc

The following code is what I've tried to find the position of the `:`. It doesn't work because `strstr` only works on `const char*`, not `unsigned char*` (the compiler gives me an error). I was going to use that index position to extract whatever is between `0` and the index (`A0`), whatever is between the index and the total length of the array (`433.22`).

I also don't know what I would use to "extract" partials from an `unsigned char*`. With strings you would probably just use `substr`.

Comment: I don't know how you create that payload, but you can probably reinterpret_cast<char*> it to use regular string methods on it.

Comment: The payload is `\0` terminated?

Comment: @JimmyB, yes it should be. I'm using the library here: https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#callback

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly is in your payload variable, you may want to simply cast it into char and apply standard string function on it.

You can find an [example here](http://cpp.sh/9scd6).